# New Note saved in a Note&Attachment relatedList

Tags: apex, notes

I want to save a new Note to a Lead via apex.

I create a new Note :

```
Note n = new Note();
n.Body = body;
n.Title=title;
n.ParentId = Id.valueOf(s); // Lead Id
n.IsPrivate = false;
Insert n;
```

But then, Its Save the Note under "Note&Attachment" related list and not under Note related list...

I know it should be super simple to rich out the answer in the internet.. But I didn't find it...

Links and answers will be much appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: Its not Note, it is ContentNote. Note is older version, which is succeeded by [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm)

Comment: I saw ContentNode but i didnt understand how to relate it with the Lead... which field should have the LeadId?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is inserting Note, which is taken over by [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) and to insert ContentNote you simply need to do the following

```
ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
cn.Title = 'test2';
String body = '<b>Hello World. Because this text is already formatted as HTML, it does not need to be escaped. 
Special characters such as &quot;, etc. must already use their HTML equivalents.</b>';
cn.Content = body;
insert(cn);
```

and then link it to the Lead record

```
ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.ContentDocumentId = cn.id; 
cdl.LinkedEntityId = 'ID of Lead';
cdl.ShareType = 'C';
cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert(cdl);
```

For details on ContentNote please refer to the documentation

- [ContentNote ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm)
- [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm)

Comment: It is not worked for me, but I found out it doesn't because it ran by a guest user over a force.com site and there is a permission issue.
When I run it from an anonymous window (dev console) It worked. So you answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating Classic Notes. Classic Notes (the `Note` sObject) are available in Lightning Experience in the Notes & Attachments related list.

Enhanced Notes (`ContentDocument`/`ContentVersion`/`ContentNote` sObjects) are shown in the Notes related list in Lightning Experience.

This is described in [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-productivity/work-with-notes-and-files):

> Enhanced notes and classic notes don’t play well together. So the enhanced Notes that you create for a record are located in the Notes related list. Any notes that you previously created for the record using the classic notes tool are in the Notes & Attachments related list.

To switch to Enhanced Notes, use the `ContentNote` sObject, with code as described in Mahmood's answer.